# SharePoint API Permissions Error for other users

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm attempting to develop a dashboard home page for users of a SharePoint site and as a part of this page I'm utilizing AJAX to make API calls to other lists within the site.

Under the context of my subsite admin account the AJAX call's are made with out issues and the JS applies the HTML correctly.

What kind of permissions will users need in order for the following JavaScript to work correctly?

```
function taskCheckListFill(){
callCurrentUser(function(userEmail){ //pulls the userEmail var from callCurrentUser into this function
    //alert(userEmail);

    var TodayDate = new Date(); //returns TodayDate var as the current Date from Date() method
    var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl; //returns the current sharepoint site url
    var dPeriod = TodayDate.getMonth(); //+1 as getMonth() method returns an index, thus Feb equals 1 and must add 1
    var sYear = TodayDate.getYear()+1900; //+1900 brings the year back to standard readable format this JS method bases years off of starting at 1900


    $.ajax({        
        url: siteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Month-End Task Checklist')/items?$filter=Period eq "+ dPeriod + " and Year eq " + sYear + " &$top=1000",
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: "",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
    success: function (data){
        var sum = 0;    
        var jsonData = data.d.results
        console.log(jsonData.length);       
        console.log(jsonData[0]);
        console.log(jsonData[0].Area);

        var step; //initializes the loop count var
        //variables below represent the status count vars placed into the grph and 
        var tasksNotStartedCount = 0;
        var tasksInProgressCount = 0;
        var tasksWaitingCount = 0;
        var tasksCompletedCount = 0


        //loop is to go from 0 to number of items in list for EVERYONE in the specified period and year
        for (step = 0; step < jsonData.length; step++){
            console.log(jsonData[step].Title);
            if(jsonData[step].Assigned_x0020_To_x002d_Email_x0 == userEmail){
            $('#myTaskChecklistTable > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>'+ jsonData[step].Title +'</td><td>'+ jsonData[step].TaskID +'</td><td>'+ jsonData[step].Due_x0020_Date+'</td><td>'+ jsonData[step].Status +'</td></tr>')
            };
            if(jsonData[step].Assigned_x0020_To_x002d_Email_x0 == userEmail && jsonData[step].Status == "Not Started"){
                tasksNotStartedCount ++
            };
            if(jsonData[step].Assigned_x0020_To_x002d_Email_x0 == userEmail && jsonData[step].Status == "In Progress"){
                tasksInProgressCount ++
            };
            if(jsonData[step].Assigned_x0020_To_x002d_Email_x0 == userEmail && jsonData[step].Status == "Waiting on someone else"){
                tasksWaitingCount ++
            };

            if(jsonData[step].Assigned_x0020_To_x002d_Email_x0 == userEmail && jsonData[step].Status == "Completed"){
                tasksCompletedCount ++
            };



            //console.log(jsonData[step].Area);
        };
        document.getElementById("taskCheckListCount_GBSHOME").innerHTML = tasksCompletedCount + "/" + (tasksNotStartedCount +tasksInProgressCount+tasksWaitingCount+tasksCompletedCount) + " completed";            
        console.log("Not started count is equal to " + tasksNotStartedCount );
        console.log("In Progress count: " + tasksInProgressCount);
        console.log("Tasks waiting on someone else count: " + tasksWaitingCount);
        console.log("Completed count is equal to " + tasksCompletedCount);
        pieChartCall1(tasksNotStartedCount, tasksInProgressCount, tasksWaitingCount, tasksCompletedCount);

        },          
    error: function (data) {
       console.log(data.responseText);
    }
}); 
});
```

};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this one by editing the permissions of ROLES (not groups assigned to roles).

The permissions that needed to be activated was "Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, Web DAV, the Client Object Model or SharePoint Designer interfaces to access the Web site."

I accessed these settings by navigating to Site Contents->Site Permissions->Clikc on Permissions Levels-> Click on specific Permissions Level hyperlink you want to edit.

Answer (score 1):

You  can add user 'Read' permission level so they could access list data.

Comment: Thanks for the help -- this didn't solve it but helped get me there. Posted the answer to my question separately.